# Mysql subquery in concat

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query and file and works fine.

Is it possible to do a subquery for product_id field (SELECT id FROM products where name = 'car') and how can I achieve that?

**File:**

```
postcode;huisnummer;toevoeging;product;datum
1775 BB;4;;CAR;02-01-2018
```

**Query:**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$path' 
INTO TABLE `temp_loc` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(@postcode,@huisnummer,@toevoeging,product,datum)
SET adres = CONCAT(REPLACE(@postcode, ' ', ''),'', @huisnummer,'$',@toevoeging);
```

**Database columns:**

```
merged_adres , product_id, datum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$path' 
INTO TABLE `temp_loc` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(@postcode,@huisnummer,@toevoeging,@product,datum)
SET adres = CONCAT(REPLACE(@postcode, ' ', ''),'', @huisnummer,'$',@toevoeging),
product = (SELECT id FROM products WHERE name = @product);
```